# Pass dictionaries or objects in REST Api calls?

Tags: c#, json, rest

I'm developing a REST Api for my business (using C#) and trying to keep it reasonably clean and simple. One of the design decisions that I'm wrestling with is say you have a resource uri:

www.mydomain.com/Api/Orders

So to create an Order you'd do a POST to this uri passing the following json:

```
{
   "ProductNumber": "12345A",
   "Quantity": 5
   "Cost" : 250.5
   "CustomerId" : "912AFD52-8F2F-43A2-87FF-EB65D0A8FD8C"
   ...etc
}
```

But on the server side I initially thought what a great idea it would be to ensure the json passed in is serialized to the underlying object model then I can just work with the object directly. However a snagging point has been around things like the Id, CreatedOn, ModifiedOn etc.

In my object model I want the Id to be generated when the object is created and the CreatedOn etc to be set when its being inserted into the db. So ideally I want those properties to be read only, but if they are read only then when the json is serialised to an object then the Id isn't populated. If don't make them read only then potentially someone could fire in json and change these properties.

So I was thinking am I just better off serialising the json to a dicationary and then just creating the objects pulling the properties from the dictionary?

I'm kind of in a muddle with the whole thing to be honest.

Comment: I think that's what a "data access layer" and "data access objects" are for... to mediate between the UI and the data store with the differences those entail.

Answer (score 0):

Just because someone says something in a request to your service doesn't mean that you have to do exactly that. An easy way would be to create a whitelist of properties that they can set, and to go through the keys of the object and remove all that are on the whitelist. Then, fill in the values that you need in there but which are server-generated. (You should also validate that the format of the values of the permitted keys is what you expect.)